# Vue.js not scaling after deployment to windows server 2019 IIS

Tags: css, vue.js, iis, windows-server-2019

After npm run serve everything's working fine. After i deployed my app with API in ASP.NET application doesnt scale at all. I use Router and History. Authentication for annonymous users is enabled and static content is installed. Console doesn't show any errors.enter image description here
Links to screenshots:

[Local run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaiH0.png)

[IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5lmv.png)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean that vue.js not scaling?  The second component display abnormally, is it right?
It might be something wrong with Javascript code snippets working.
Did you install the URL Rewrite extension in IIS and add the below rules in the `webconfig` file?

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Handle History Mode and custom 404/500" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Here is URL Rewrite extension.
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite